# can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

On one pc i am getting this on ruby 1.8.6 and on other pc i am getting error

```
irb(main):001:0> buff = "12345678"
 => "12345678"
 irb(main):002:0> buff[4] =0x30
  => 48
   irb(main):003:0> buff
 => "12340678"
 irb(main):004:0> @new0 = "123456789"
 => "123456789"
  irb(main):005:0> @new0[4] = 0x30 
 => 48


 > @buff ="123456789"
 => "123456789" 
  > @buff
 => "123456789" 
 > @buff[4]= 0x30
 TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
from (irb):3:in `[]='
from (irb):3

  > @buff[4] = 0x30
```

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.9 in the 2nd block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are using Ruby 1.9 in your second example. The `[]=` method has changed and only accepts strings.

You can convert an integer value to a string using [`chr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
@buff[4] = 0x30.chr
```

And retrieve a character's byte value with:

```
@buff[4].ord
# => 48
```