# ruby assign hex value to string

Tags: ruby

This code is working on the older versions   1.8.X

```
 @buff1 = "12"
 @buff1[0] = 0x0b                                   
 @buff1[1] = 0x0e
```

I have udpated small part of code . Please have a look again. because in `1.8.6` I get `"\016\v"`  as output and in `1.9.3` showing error `TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String`

Please provide solution for 1.9.3

Comment: Why provide `b` if it's never used?

Comment: @hbdev, Something's lacking in the code snippet.  Is the `b = "12"` explaining what you expect @buff1 to be set to after the code is run?

Comment: what the output you want to see?

Comment: Sorry .. I have updated the code. Please have a look again

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006955/cant-convert-fixnum-into-string-typeerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in **`Ruby 1.9.3`**

```
p RUBY_VERSION
b = "12"
@buff1 = []
@buff1[0] = 0x0b                                   
@buff1[1] = 0x0e
p @buff1
```

*Output:*

```
"1.9.3"
[11, 14]
```

Probably you tried:

```
p RUBY_VERSION
b = "12" # you missed the statement @buff1 = []
@buff1[0] = 0x0b                                   
@buff1[1] = 0x0e
p @buff1
```

And you got the below output:

```
"1.9.3"
C:/Documents and Settings/rakshiar/My Documents/userdata/Ruby/Scripts/test.rb:11
9:in `<main>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Hope this code will help you.

**UPDATE**

```
p RUBY_VERSION
@buff1 = "12"
@buff1[0] = 0x0b.to_s  
p @buff1                               
@buff1[1] = 0x0e.to_s
p @buff1
```

*Output:*

```
"1.9.3"
"112"
"1142"
```

Comment: I have udpated small part of code . Please have a look again. because in `1.8.6 ` I get `"\016\v" `  as answer as `1.9.3` showing error `TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String`

Comment: @hbdevror what is your expected output?